# Delimiter in Scanner Java confusion

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

According to Java API Scanner uses delimiters to break the whole input into tokens. I am trying to understand the tokens and delimiters. I was doing this program and hit a confusion

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = null;
        try {
            s = new Scanner(System.in);
            s.useDelimiter("A");
            System.out.println("1 " + s.next().length());
            System.out.println("2 " + s.next().length());
            System.out.println("3 " + s.next().length());
            System.out.println("4 " + s.next().length());
        } finally {
            if (s != null) {
                s.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I use the input `AAAAAasdf` I get the following output.

```
1 0
2 0
3 0
4 0
```

I can understand this output as the length of tokens is zero between the delimiters hence all are zero but when I use the default delimiters and give the input as

`_____aaa\n` ->Replace underscore by space and `\n` by me hitting enter in eclipse console.

For this I am getting the output as

```
1 3
```

which I cannot understand. I have given 5 spaces so there should be 4 tokens of 0 lengths between them. Why not? What am I missing here?

Comment: i would assume scanner skips the spaces

Comment: @njzk2 It works according to regex patterns. See the most upvoted answer and API reference in the comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

useDelimiter takes a regular expression pattern.  The default pattern is

```
private static Pattern WHITESPACE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(
                                            "\\p{javaWhitespace}+");
```

Which will match any amount of contiguous whitespace.  If you want the delimiter to match any amount of contiguous A try something like

```
s.useDelimiter("[A]+");
```

Read these: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter(java.lang.String)
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#reset()

Comment: Correct answer. Found it in API reference. Please add that also. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#reset()

Comment: If anyone is interested here is link to OpenJDK. Search for `WHITESPACE_PATTERN`and you'll see the statement given in this answer. http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/Scanner.java

Answer (score 0):

Its really interesting to see that when we specify " " (empty space) as a delimiter in the code

```
    try {
        s = new Scanner(System.in);
        s.useDelimiter(" ");
        System.out.println("1 " + s.next().length());
        System.out.println("2 " + s.next().length());
        System.out.println("3 " + s.next().length());
        System.out.println("4 " + s.next().length());
    } finally {
        if (s != null) {
            s.close();
        }
    }
```

and the input is

```
[5 spaces]asdf
```

we see the output

```
1 0
2 0
3 0
4 0
```

But when we dont specify the delimiter,

```
    try {
        s = new Scanner(System.in);
        //s.useDelimiter(" ");
        System.out.println("1 " + s.next().length());
        System.out.println("2 " + s.next().length());
        System.out.println("3 " + s.next().length());
        System.out.println("4 " + s.next().length());
    } finally {
        if (s != null) {
            s.close();
        }
    }
```

The same input

```
[5 spaces]asdf
```

generates a different output

```
1 4
```

So, i think specifying the delimiter, even though a default one makes the scanner skip all empty tokens.

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner.next()` function Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the `delimiter pattern`. The default pattern is `\\p{javaWhitespace}+`.

To understand it better, try etting delimiter  `"\\s*"`:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
scanner.useDelimiter("\\s*");
while(scanner.hasNext())
  System.out.println(scanner.next());
```

For an input `123`, it `scanner.next()` will print:

```
1  // first println
2  //snd println
3 // third println
```

As `X*` says that pattern `X` can occur *zero* or more times. This expression is known as [*Quantifiers*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html). However an expression `X+` says that `X, one or more times`. So try using delimiter `"[A]+"` which says that `"A"` occurs one or more time, and matches any amount of contiguous `"A"`